# While loop shortcode problem

Tags: shortcode

I have created a shortcode  using the while loop, which is going to break the loop when used with the page builder. How to solve it.
Here may custom shortcode
[image]
here my showing part
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use global `$wp_query` object anywhere in your code, so there is no point in calling `wp_reset_query()`.

On the other hand, you do use global `$post` variable, so after your code you should restore it's original value with `wp_reset_postdata();`.

So change `wp_reset_query()` to `wp_reset_postdata()` and it should be OK.

### And one more thing...

Shortcodes should return their values and they should not display anything.

So you can't use `the_title()` inside of it - this template tags echoes its value and doesn't return anything.

You should change it to `get_the_title()`.